# Facing issue with Openstack Rocky version in retrieving the instances and connecting to VM's

Tags: openstack

Facing issue with Openstack (Rocky version) in retrieving the instances i.e **Error unable to retrieve instance** and also in connecting to VM's. By mistake, we have run apt upgrade in the controller machine. Can system upgrades be the reason for OpenStack malfunction?  Also when we checked the status of neutron-openvswitch-agent in compute node and seen the below log:

```
root@compute-I:/home/user# systemctl status neutron-openvswitch-agent

● neutron-openvswitch-agent.service - Openstack Neutron Open vSwitch Plugin Agent
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/neutron-openvswitch-agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

  **Active: active (running)** since Tue 2021-09-07 20:42:39 IST; 43s ago

 Process: 13632 ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe br_netfilter (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 13631 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown neutron:neutron /var/lock/neutron /var/log/neutron /var/lib/neutron (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 13630 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/lock/neutron /var/log/neutron /var/lib/neutron (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 13633 (neutron-openvsw)
   Tasks: 3 (limit: 22118)
  CGroup: /system.slice/neutron-openvswitch-agent.service
          ├─13633 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/neutron-openvswitch-agent --config-file=/etc/neutron/neutron.conf --config-file=/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/openvswitch_age
          ├─13651 ovsdb-client monitor tcp:127.0.0.1:6640 Interface name,ofport,external_ids --format=json
          └─13656 ovsdb-client monitor tcp:127.0.0.1:6640 Bridge name --format=json

Sep 07 20:42:41 compute-I ovs-vsctl[13650]: ovs|00001|vsctl|INFO|Called as /usr/bin/ovs-vsctl --timeout=5 --id=@manager -- create Manager "target=\"ptcp:6640:127.0.0.1

**Sep 07 20:42:41 compute-I ovs-vsctl[13650]: ovs|00002|ovsdb_idl|WARN|transaction error: {"details":"Transaction causes multiple rows in \"Manager\" table to have ident**

Sep 07 20:42:41 compute-I ovs-vsctl[13650]: ovs|00003|db_ctl_base|ERR|transaction error: {"details":"Transaction causes multiple rows in \"Manager\" table to have iden

Sep 07 20:42:41 compute-I sudo[13647]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root

Sep 07 20:42:41 compute-I sudo[13652]:  neutron : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/var/lib/neutron ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/neutron-rootwrap /etc/neutron/rootwrap.conf ovs-vsc

Sep 07 20:42:41 compute-I sudo[13652]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)

Sep 07 20:42:41 compute-I ovs-vsctl[13655]: ovs|00001|vsctl|INFO|Called as /usr/bin/ovs-vsctl --timeout=5 --id=@manager -- create Manager "target=\"ptcp:6640:127.0.0.1

Sep 07 20:42:41 compute-I ovs-vsctl[13655]: ovs|00002|ovsdb_idl|WARN|transaction error: {"details":"Transaction causes multiple rows in \"Manager\" table to have ident

Sep 07 20:42:41 compute-I ovs-vsctl[13655]: ovs|00003|db_ctl_base|ERR|transaction error: {"details":"Transaction causes multiple rows in \"Manager\" table to have iden

Sep 07 20:42:41 compute-I sudo[13652]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with neutron service in this case. We followed **Finalize installation** steps given at the end of the page in the link:
*https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/rocky/install/controller-install-ubuntu.html*
and could resolve the issue. After running the steps we could see our instances on the dashboard.